# Добавить запятую в регулярных php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Никак с этими регулярками не могу разобраться. Вроде банальная задача, а выхода не могу найти.

```
preg_replace('/\)[A-Za-z0-9]/i', "$0,", '(name-text-1)name-text-2')
// выведет: (name-text-1)n, ame-text-2
// а хотелось: (name-text-1), name-text-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> '/\)[A-Za-z0-9]/i'
> ```

```
'/[A-Za-z0-9]\)/i'
```

```
'/\)/'
```

> ```
> ((name-text-1))name-text-2
> ```

```
'/\)(?!\))/'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только вот не могу понять, как быть с такой строкой, `((name-text-1))name-text-2`, выводится `((name-text-1), )name-text-2`. В чем ошибка?

Comment: хотелось получить вот такой результат `((name-text-1)), name-text-2`

Comment: @dgdhsk, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Ого супер! Спасибо большое

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ через 4 минуты